# Open Activity and populate based off ListView selection

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to pass data from a custom listview to a new activity and populate its TextViews. It does work but it always takes the first position that was added and passes it through. How do I get it to pass the data clicked on?

**MainActivity**

```
package uk.co.jaunt_app.jaunt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers;
import com.crashlytics.android.answers.CustomEvent;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static uk.co.jaunt_app.jaunt.R.id.Posts;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton addmap;
    private Button settingbtn;
    private TextView mNameTextView;
    private TextView mEmailTextView;
    ListView mPosts;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ArrayList<feed> feedPop = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.jauntlogodark);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String uid = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
        Firebase usersRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name");
        Firebase emailRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("email");
        Firebase postRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("Maps");

        postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (final DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot

                    Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                    final String mapName = person.getMapName();
                    final String mapid = person.getMapID();
                    final String mapStartLat = person.getStartLat();
                    final String mapStartLong = person.getStartLong();
                    final String mapEndLat = person.getEndLat();
                    final String mapEndLong = person.getEndLong();

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    feedPop.add(
                            new feed(mapName, mapStartLat, mapStartLong, mapEndLat, mapEndLong));

                    final ArrayAdapter<feed> adapter = new feedArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, 0, feedPop);

                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewUserMapActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("mapName", mapName.toString());
                            intent.putExtra("mapStartLat", mapStartLat.toString());
                            intent.putExtra("mapStartLong", mapStartLong.toString());
                            intent.putExtra("mapEndLat", mapEndLat.toString());
                            intent.putExtra("mapEndLong", mapEndLong.toString());
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        //create property elements


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        mPosts = (ListView) findViewById(Posts);
        mPosts.setAdapter(adapter);

        List<Nav> navList= new ArrayList<Nav>();
        navList.add(new Nav("Profile"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Feed"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Maps"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Most Popular"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Settings"));
        navList.add(new Nav("Report a Bug"));

        ArrayAdapter<Nav> navadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Nav>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, navList);
        final ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        lv.setAdapter(navadapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int itemPosition = position;

                switch(itemPosition) {

                    case 0:
                        Intent menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        menuItem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserMapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(menuItem);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NameTextView);

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mNameTextView.setText(name);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        mEmailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EmailTextView);

        emailRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String email = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mEmailTextView.setText(email);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });



        addmap = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_map);
        addmap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Added Map"));
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapStartActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        settingbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingbtn);
        settingbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

}

//custom ArrayAdapter
class feedArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<feed>{

    private Context context;
    private List<feed> feedPop;

    //constructor, call on creation
    public feedArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<feed> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.feedPop = objects;
    }

    //called when rendering the list
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //get the property we are displaying
        feed feed = feedPop.get(position);

        //get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_listview, null);

        TextView others = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.others);
        TextView mapname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);

        //set address and description
        String completeOthers = feed.getFeedStartLat() + ", " + feed.getFeedStartLong() + ", " + feed.getFeedEndLat() + ", " + feed.getFeedEndLong();
        others.setText(completeOthers);

        //set address and description
        String completeAddress = feed.getFeedName();
        mapname.setText(completeAddress);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you think more closely about the design of your code. As it is currently, you are completely recreating the UI every time the data in Firebase changes. Instead, you should set up the UI once in `onCreate()` and only update the relevant parts when the underlying data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get value from ArrayList based on position then pass to activity

```
intent.putExtra("mapName", feedPop.get(position).getmapName().toString());
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you very much!